# How do I prevent my function from modifying a string within a constant?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an issue with a RegEx pattern collection I am setting, along with many other resources, within an angular constant. In this example, the RegExPattern has a '\' character, which angular is stripping from the string. This renders the pattern useless.

http://jsfiddle.net/beauxjames/u8sevn6k/

```
.constant('appConfig', {
    RegExPattern: '^\d{9}$'     
})
```

I am familiar with $sce and safely encoding HTML, but not from within a constant.

What are my options here?

Comment: What is the "function" and what is the "constant"? How is it modifying the string? Can you post the output string after the function modifies it?

Comment: just in case you don't see the solution in all the banter below --> new RegExp('^\d{9}$') and then js didn't strip the '\'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslashes have to be escaped in strings...

```
.constant('appConfig', {
    RegExPattern: '^\\d{9}$'     
})
```

Or you can use a regex literal

```
.constant('appConfig', {
    RegExPattern: /^\d{9}$/
})
```

EDIT:

This has nothing to do with angular, javascript does this by itself (uses backslash as escape character)

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c3v10owy/) for yourself

Comment: besides...your second 'answer' still has the backslash...it gets junked

Comment: my second answer is not a string, is a regex literal

Comment: @beauXjames If you can't modify the resource, there's nothing you can do. It's the javascript engine that is striping your backslash, not angular

Comment: ok ok...so the question is fouled up...as was my inspection of the situation. you ended up being correct...it was just js all along stripping it out. I don't want to modify the resource due to these patterns being shared across other code bases as well...js is the only one that likes the /pattern/. I did, however, get away with new RegExp('^\d{9}$') and then js didn't strip the '\'.

Comment: @beauXjames yup. `new RegExp('^\d{9}$') == /^\d{9}$/`

Answer (score 0):

Double `\` `RegExPattern: '^\\d{9}$'`

Comment: @beauXjames it is the answer. If you need to update your question, please do so.

Comment: not if i don't want to modify the resource, it isn't/wasn't